# pyautogui.write writes jumbled-up characters

Tags: python, macos, automation, pyautogui

I am trying to automate a renaming task on Google Web Designer. pyautogui.write writes completely wring letters. for example:

```py
 pyautogui.write("This is a sample text 12345/._-")
```

returns this text
`This is q sq,ple text &é”’(=:°)`

This is not an AZERTY QWERTY issue, and I've tried writing to other applications but it still has the same issue.

I am guessing it's because I'm using a mac. But not sure how to solve it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
import keyboard

keyboard.write("This is a sample text 12345/._-")

Try this ;)
```

pip install keyboard